# Can I use custom trafic data for here API?

Tags: maps, here-api

I've just created a tool that produces real-time trafic data. I'd like to plot the results with here-api. I know that Here provides a trafic display api, but I can't figure out how to define my own datasource.

Thanks !

Comment: Are you referring to the JS API?
In which format does your tool provide the traffic data? GeoJSON, image tiles?

Comment: Well I can pretty much produce any data format. At the moment I have a bunch of polylines (that I will very soon store in a PostGre DB), and I can export them in GeoJSON easily. I'd be happy to make any necessary transformation.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. You've created a tool that has the same function HERE does. If you just want to plot traffic, try Google MyMaps. Maybe GIS platforms?

btw, how did you manage to collect traffic data for this tool?

Comment: At the moment the trafic data is very poor. It is based on monthly averages by road types and by region. I want to compare this poor representation to fresh trafic data to start with.

Why ? Well the last step will be to introduce these as features in a machine learning algorithm, but that is not for today :)